# jqgrid setColProp not working when data type is url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

We are using jquery grid 4.6. We want to set a `select box` for filter toolbar.  The select box should have columns unique name, this has already been answered and the solution could be found at: https://jsfiddle.net/4k0xgxok/

How ever when we change the `data` from `local` to `url` the `search box` will not appear at all. I tried to make a simple sample which only change the `searchoptions:value` to some thing hard coded, but it does not work. https://jsfiddle.net/xdbw5hmy/

The code is

```
    var getUniqueNames = function(columnName) {
      var texts = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getCol', columnName),
        uniqueTexts = [],
        textsLength = texts.length,
        text, textsMap = {},
        i;
      for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
        text = texts[i];
        if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
          // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
          textsMap[text] = true;
          uniqueTexts.push(text);
        }
      }
      return uniqueTexts;
    };
    var  buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
        var values=":All";
        $.each (uniqueNames, function() {
            values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
        });
        console.log(values);
        return values;
    };
    var mydata = [{
      "OrderId": "1",
      "CategoryName": "Beverages",
      "ProductName": "Steeleye Stout"
    }, {
      "OrderId": "2",
      "CategoryName": "Beverages",
      "ProductName": "Laughing Lumberjack Lager"
    }];
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
      datatype: 'local',
      data: mydata,
      colModel: [{
        label: 'OrderID',
        name: 'OrderID',
        key: true,
        width: 75
      }, {
        label: 'ProductName',
        name: 'ProductName',
        width: 150
      }, {
        label: 'CategoryName',
        name: 'CategoryName',
        width: 150
      }],
      gridComplete: function() {
        $('#jqGrid').jqGrid("setColProp", "ProductName", {
          stype: "select",
          align: "center",
          searchoptions: {
            value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames("ProductName")),
          }
        });
      },
      viewrecords: true,
      height: 250,
      rowNum: 20,
    });
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar');
  });
```

Comment: You wrote "we change the data from local to url". It seems be incorrect. You mean probably that you change `datatype: "local", data: mydata` to `datatype: "json", url: "someUrl", loadonce: true`. Is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code: the usage of `gridComplete` to set the column properties and the usage of `getCol` inside of `getUniqueNames`. The method `getCol` uses only the data from **the current page**, but you should take in consideration *all data* returned from the server. The second problem: you should set `searchoptions.value` only **once** after loading the data from the server. On the other side `gridComplete` will be called after every paging, sorting and so on. Finally it's very important to call `filterToolbar` **after** the new settings `searchoptions.value` are already set. The code from your demo https://jsfiddle.net/xdbw5hmy/ will first create the filter toolbar, before and data are loaded from the server and before `searchoptions.value` is set.

What you should do is the usage of `beforeProcessing` callback instead of `gridComplete`. The callback `beforeProcessing` get **full data** returned from the server as the parameter. One can scan the data and to call `setColProp` to modify `searchoptions.value`. After that one can create the filter toolbar by calling of `filterToolbar`. You will get the code like below

```
var getUniqueNames = function(columnName, mydata) {
        var texts = $.map(mydata, function(item) {
            return item[columnName];
        }),
            uniqueTexts = [],
            textsLength = texts.length,
            text, textsMap = {},
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
            text = texts[i];
            if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                textsMap[text] = true;
                uniqueTexts.push(text);
            }
        }
        return uniqueTexts;
    },
    buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
        var values = "";
        $.each(uniqueNames, function() {
            values += this + ":" + this + ";";
        });
        values = values.slice(0, -1);
        return values;
    },
    setSearchSelect = function(columnName, data) {
        $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", columnName, {
            stype: "select",
            align: "center",
            searchoptions: {
                value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames.call(this, columnName, data)),
                sopt: ["eq", "ne"]
            }
        });
    },
    myDefaultSearch = "cn";

$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/42mdc',
    datatype: 'json',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'OrderID', key: true, width: 75 },
        { name: 'ProductName' },
        { name: 'CategoryName' }
    ],
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        // !!! it will be called only after loading from the server
        // datatype is always "json" here
        setSearchSelect.call(this, "ProductName", data.rows);

        if (this.ftoolbar === true) {
            // if the filter toolbar already exist: we have to recreate it
            $(this).jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar');
        }
        $(this).jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
            stringResult: true,
            defaultSearch: myDefaultSearch
        });
    },
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",
    autoencode: true,
    rowNum: 20,
    loadonce: true
});
```

See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/xdbw5hmy/1/

By the way, I recommend you co consider to use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) instead of the standard `<select>`. It's much more comfortable for the user if one has many items of data because `select2` has integrated search input field and the selected data will be reduced during the user types the text. Look at the demos from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876387/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475971/315935). I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935), which demonstrates `beforeProcessing`.